# Downgrading Phonegap 3.0 to 2.9 on Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm getting impatient with Phonegap 3.0, as there are many issues such as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579571/cordova-ios-7-adding-black-gap-for-keyboard)

From the CLI, how do I downgrade to 2.9?

Answer (score 1):

If this could answer your question:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/howto_downgrade_ios_project_from_3_0_0_to_2_9_0

Comment: I tried that.  Is it supposed to be done in the project folder, or in the platforms/ios folder?

Comment: So is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just download the 2.9 code  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.0.zip

Unzip and drop the Phonegap>ios>bin folder on top of your terminal icon. to open a bin:terminal.

Then use the code to create a new app

```
./create ~/Desktop/NewAppFolder com.company.newapp AppName
```

Open the newley created folder on Desktop and double click the .xcodeproj and new app in PG2.9

Comment: Would this copy all of my Xcode 5 resources too, such as the .xcassets file?

Comment: From what I understand it will create a xcodeproj file that will open in whatever xcode you are running, and you can edit file etc as wanted